# http url for local files asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have a `treeview` for a folder under my **application folder.** I would like to provide links to the files in the folder. The folder might have sub folders and so on. How can I provide **http urls** in the links.

When I do this I only get the physical location of the file instead of the http url.

```
Path.Combine(file.DirectoryName, file.Name)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `Control.ResolveUrl` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the root of the application.

```
var root = Server.MapPath("~");
```

Now, do what you need, iterate over files/directories. You can simply combine the paths like so:

```
foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory
                         .GetFiles(System.IO.Path.Combine(root, "Images")))
{
    // This will give you the relative URL of each file.
    var fileUrl = ResolveUrl(file.Replace(root, string.Empty).Replace("\\", "/"));
}
```

Comment: This is what I had to add to get the correct urls.                   var fileUrl = ResolveUrl("~/" + file.Replace(root, string.Empty).Replace("\\", "/"));